# Quick and Dirty Notification JQuery

Tags: jquery, notifications

I have a notification function that just adds a `<div class="notification"></div>` to `#notification-area`.

I need to have the notification fade out after 5 seconds of a single notification being there.
I could do it if I had access to the div I just added.

possibly `$('.notification:last-child')` to select it?

Comment: How do you add the div?

Comment: looks ok - did you try it?  Would probably have taken less time than writing this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var notification = $('<div class="notification"></div>');

$('#notification-area').append(notification);

setTimeout(function(){
    notification.fadeOut();
    notification.remove();
},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.notification').last();
```

Would select the last `.notification` element.

See http://api.jquery.com/last/